# Is a given name made up of two names separated by a hyphen called a double-barrelled given name?

Tags: british-english

Such given names are quite common in certain cultures. For instance, in France, you might find people having the first name Charles-Édouard or Xavier-Luc.

Surnames in that form are referred to as double-barrelled surnames. Yet, the corresponding term for given names cannot be found on [the Wikipedia article for given names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Given_name).

So, what is the term for it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132411/discussion-on-question-by-peanutjelly-is-a-given-name-made-up-of-two-names-separ).

Answer (score 0):

**Double-barrelled** is used for this type of name, but in the UK **hyphenated** is also common. My study is based on a few different websites in the UK, including parenting and women's magazines and blogs. There are other forms of double names, and not all use hyphens, but the question is about hyphenated forms.

[An article in Psychology Today UK](https://www.psychologytoday.com/gb/blog/whats-in-name/201406/the-psychology-double-names) uses "double names" for names with two elements which may or may not include a hyphen, but also uses the word "hyphenated".

[Marie Claire UK](https://www.marieclaire.co.uk/life/sex-and-relationships/most-popular-double-barrelled-baby-names-uk-695926) says "double-barrelled".

[The Sun newspaper](https://www.thesun.co.uk/fabulous/5567796/mum-sparks-fierce-debate-asking-hyphenated-names-chavvy/) in an article says hyphenated.

[Mother and Baby magazine](https://www.motherandbaby.co.uk/baby-names/girls/unique-double-barreled-girls-names/) uses double-barrelled.

[U Me And The Kids](https://umeandthekids.com/hyphenated-first-names-for-girls-boys/) a British blog says hyphenated.

[Emma's Diary](https://www.emmasdiary.co.uk/lifestyle/fun-facts/hyphenated-names) another British blog says hyphenated.

Comment: Even for surnames, I'd say “double-barrelled” is rare in the rebellious colonies.

Answer (score -3):

Yes.

I checked with my 1976 edition of The Concise Oxford Dictionary of Current  English to confirm and, in case it has changed recently, the app version says the same:

> double-barrelled /ˌdʌb(ə)lˈbarəld/
>
> adjective
>
> 1     (of a gun) having two barrels. ▪  having two parts or aspects
> 2      British      (of a surname) having two
> parts joined by a hyphen.

Comment: The question is about given names, not surnames.